# What should I do to improve the DFS Java implementation, to solve the problem?

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search

I am trying to solve the problem called Walls and Gates.

Here is the problem link.
https://leetcode.com/problems/walls-and-gates/description/

> You are given a m X n grid, rooms initialized with these three possible values.
>
> - -1 A wall or an obstacle.
> - 0 A gate.
> - INF Infinity means an empty room.
>
>   We use the value 2<sup>31</sup> - 1 = 2147483647 to represent INF as you may assume that the distance to a gate is less than 2147483647.
>
> Fill each empty room with the distance to its nearest gate. If it is impossible to reach a gate, it should be filled with INF.

I am trying to use DFS to solve the above problem.

My approach is to

- Traverse the grid using two indexes i and j.
- And wherever I encounter a 0 cell value, I start a DFS, as this is a Gate as per the problem definition.
- In the DFS algorithm, I first check the boundaries are satisfied or not.

  - If out of boundary, then I return.
  - If the cell value is -1 then also I return, since as per the problem condition it is a wall.
  - If the cell is already traversed then also I return.

  After all the above cases, I find out the minimum of cell value and count, and update the current cell with the minimum.
- Mark the cell as visited. For which I am using another boolean grid.
- And then I traverse all the cell by doing, row + 1, row - 1, cell + 1, cell -1.

Here is the code:

```
class Solution {
    public void wallsAndGates(int[][] rooms) {
        boolean[][] roomsBool = new boolean[rooms.length][rooms[0].length];
        for(int i = 0; i < rooms.length; ++i){
            for(int j = 0; j < rooms[i].length; ++j){
                if(rooms[i][j] == 0){
                    //if it is a gate we will do a DFS and fill the cells with the appropriate values.
                    visitRommsDFS(rooms, i, j, 0, roomsBool);
                    roomsBool = new boolean[rooms.length][rooms[i].length];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void visitRommsDFS(int[][] rooms, int row, int col, int count, boolean[][] roomsBool){
        if(row < 0 || row >= rooms.length || col < 0 || col >= rooms[row].length || rooms[row][col] == -1 || roomsBool[row][col] == true || rooms[row][col] == 0 && count > 0) return;
        if(rooms[row][col] > 0){
            rooms[row][col] = Math.min(rooms[row][col], count);
        }
        roomsBool[row][col] = true;
        visitRommsDFS(rooms, row-1, col, count + 1, roomsBool);
        visitRommsDFS(rooms, row+1, col, count + 1, roomsBool);
        visitRommsDFS(rooms, row, col+1, count + 1, roomsBool);
        visitRommsDFS(rooms, row, col-1, count + 1, roomsBool);
    }
}
```

Problem is this code is not correct and is not giving the required correct result, what is that is lacking in this solution? What should I add to make this solution to make it fool proof?

Here is the sample input for the problem.

```
[
    [0, 2147483647, -1, 2147483647, 2147483647, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 2147483647, 2147483647, 0, -1, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 0, 2147483647, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2147483647, -1, -1, 2147483647, 2147483647, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 2147483647, 0, 2147483647, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 2147483647],
    [2147483647, 0, -1, 2147483647, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 2147483647, 2147483647, -1, -1, 2147483647, -1, -1, 2147483647, 2147483647, -1, 0, -1, 2147483647, 0, 2147483647, -1, 2147483647, 0, 2147483647, 0, 2147483647, -1, 2147483647, 0, 2147483647, -1, 2147483647, 0, 2147483647, 2147483647, 0, -1, 2147483647, -1, -1, -1, 0, 2147483647]
]
```

and here is my output.

```
[
    [0, 1, -1, 2, 1, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 2, 0, -1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, -1, -1, 1, 2, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, -1, 3, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 2, 1, -1, -1, 4, -1, -1, 1, 2, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1]
]
```

while here is the expected output.

```
[
    [0, 1, -1, 2, 1, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, -1, -1, 1, 2, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1, 4, -1, -1, 1, 2, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1]
]
```

Some more sample input and their expected outputs are as follows :-

> 1. Sample input

```
[
    [2147483647, -1, 0, 2147483647],
    [2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, -1],
    [2147483647, -1, 2147483647, -1],
    [0, -1, 2147483647, 2147483647]
]
```

> Expected output of Sample output 1.

```
 [
    [3, -1, 0, 1],
    [2, 2, 1, -1],
    [1, -1, 2, -1],
    [0, -1, 3, 4]
]
```

> Sample input 2.

```
[
    [-1]
]
```

> Expected output for sample input 2.

```
[
    [-1]
]
```

Comment: "*Problem is this code is not correct and is not giving the required correct result*" Give us a sample input. Tell us the expected result and the actual result. That both allows us to reproduce exactly what you're doing, and avoids the possibility that it's not the code, but *your expectations* that are wrong.

Comment: Agreed, and those things are now added in the question. Please see and let me know any other shortcomings, thanks.

Comment: Please see [mcve], emphasis on *minimal*.

Comment: Note that the linked problem is behind a subscription wall.

Comment: DFS is not appropriate for this problem.  You should use BFS to find the distance to each cell from a gate.

Comment: @MattTimmermans that would be easier, yes I agree, but we can use DFS, I mean in principle, may not be super efficient, the count value would decrement when we backtrack in DFS and the cells should be having an appropriate value!! 
Please correct me if I am wrong!!

Comment: Yes, you are wrong.  A "distance" is a shortest path length.  BFS follows shortest paths.  DFS does not.

Comment: So the count values in the above algorithm will not be giving us the correct distance of the cell from the gate cell. Hmm...
Is this the logical flaw in my solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is you are marking the room as seen before figuring out whether you have found shortest path or not:

```
    private void visitRommsDFS(int[][] rooms, int row, int col, int count, boolean[][] roomsBool){
        if(... roomsBool[row][col] == true ...) {
            return;
        }
        if(rooms[row][col] > 0){
            rooms[row][col] = Math.min(rooms[row][col], count);
        }
        roomsBool[row][col] = true;
        // 1
        visitRommsDFS(rooms, row-1, col, count + 1, roomsBool);
        // 2
        visitRommsDFS(rooms, row+1, col, count + 1, roomsBool);
        // 3
        visitRommsDFS(rooms, row, col+1, count + 1, roomsBool);
        // 4
        visitRommsDFS(rooms, row, col-1, count + 1, roomsBool);
    }
```

i.e. call(1) is poisoning all reachable cells in `roomsBool` with `true` value, and, so, calls (2), (3) and (4) might have no effect.

Quick fix is to revert `roomsBool` state back at the end of `visitRommsDFS` call:

```java
roomsBool[row][col] = true;
visitRommsDFS(rooms, row - 1, col, count + 1, roomsBool);
visitRommsDFS(rooms, row + 1, col, count + 1, roomsBool);
visitRommsDFS(rooms, row, col + 1, count + 1, roomsBool);
visitRommsDFS(rooms, row, col - 1, count + 1, roomsBool);
roomsBool[row][col] = false;
```

---

Well... I'm actually not sure it is worth trying optimize that puzzle without relevant test data, by the way...

your current algorithm is: let find all rooms with gates and traverse all rooms reachable from particular gate, time complexity for such naive algorithm is obviously *worse than* `O(MxNxG)`, the best you can get here is to stop traversing rooms if room is closer to "another" gate rather than to the current one, something like:

```java
public static final int[][] DIRS = new int[][]{new int[]{-1, 0}, new int[]{1, 0}, new int[]{0, -1}, new int[]{0, 1}};

public void wallsAndGates(int[][] rooms) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rooms.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < rooms[i].length; ++j) {
            if (rooms[i][j] == 0) {
                visitRoomsDFS(rooms, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void visitRoomsDFS(int[][] rooms, int row, int col) {
    int distance = rooms[row][col] + 1;
    for (int[] dir : DIRS) {
        int r = row + dir[0];
        int c = col + dir[1];
        if (r < 0 || c < 0 || r >= rooms.length || c >= rooms[row].length) {
            continue;
        }
        // optimization: "have seen better" or not a room
        if (rooms[r][c] <= distance) {
            continue;
        }
        rooms[r][c] = distance;
        visitRoomsDFS(rooms, r, c);
    }

}
```

However, I believe that even with such optimization the time complexity is still *not better than* `O(MxNxG)`, on the other hand the *theoretical* time complexity for this puzzle should not be better than `O(MxN)` - we need to traverse all rooms anyway, and the problem is the algorithm with `O(MxN)` time complexity does exist:

the main idea is to traverse rooms in very specific order:

- at first we traverse gates
- at second we traverse gate's neighbours - such rooms either have distance `1` to some gate or are the walls or we have seen them before
- at third we traverse all neighbours of rooms having distance `1` to some gate - such rooms either have distance `2` to some gate or are the walls or we have seen them before.
- etc

```java
public static final int[][] DIRS = new int[][]{new int[]{-1, 0}, new int[]{1, 0}, new int[]{0, -1}, new int[]{0, 1}};

public void wallsAndGates(int[][] rooms) {
    int rows = rooms.length;
    int cols = rooms[0].length;
    Deque<int[]> deque = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            if (rooms[i][j] == 0) {
                deque.add(new int[]{i, j});
            }
        }
    }
    int[] room;
    while ((room = deque.pollFirst()) != null) {
        int distance = rooms[room[0]][room[1]] + 1;
        for (int[] dir : DIRS) {
            int r = room[0] + dir[0];
            int c = room[1] + dir[1];
            if (r < 0 || c < 0 || r >= rows || c >= cols) {
                continue;
            }
            // ignoring walls and rooms
            // seen previously
            if (rooms[r][c] > distance) {
                rooms[r][c] = distance;
                deque.addLast(new int[]{r, c});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This, that is poisoning all reachable cells, is a peculiarity of recursion. Is n't it? Please explain something more about it.

 Can something be done to make this execute little faster, as well

Comment: The obvious optimisation is: you are currently traversing the whole matrix to compare path's length, on the other hand, I believe, you may stop traversing matrix as soon as all neighbours have already shorter path.

Comment: How would I know the path, that I have found is the most optimized and is the shotest path which exists for the neighbors, and no further processing is required for those cells!! 
Also please say something more about the poisoning of all reachable cells, seems  I need to understand it bit more.

Comment: Please add some more detail to the already very good answer. Little details you add, and make this an excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @Andrey B. Panfilov is correct, but the implementation provided, idea wise, is not very distinct from what I have done, apart from, of course, the mistake that I was doing of, not backtracking correctly, by not marking the auxiliary boolean array cell value as false again, at the end, it should be done precisely at the end of all traversals on all of the various sides.

```
roomsBool[row][col] = false;
```

This above step is crucial, to backtrack.

Also, just one check that the rooms[row][col] is less than count :-

```
if(rooms[row][col] < count) {
  rooms[row][col] = count;
}
```

won't guarantee that the smallest value is being stored in that cell, we must let recursion decide this, that which one is the shortest path, this will be done when we recurse to the cell from the various directions, and to enable recursion do that, that is allow it to come from the various sides to the cell under consideration, we must make

```
roomsBool[row][col] = false;
```

after traversing in all 4 directions.

And the optimization suggested, can be easily incorporated in my solution as well.
Here is the complete working solution.

```
  class Solution {
    public void wallsAndGates(int[][] rooms) {

        boolean[][] roomsBool = new boolean[rooms.length][rooms[0].length];

        for(int i = 0; i < rooms.length; ++i){
            for(int j = 0; j < rooms[i].length; ++j){
                if(rooms[i][j] == 0){
                    //if it is a gate we will do a DFS and fill the cells with the appropriate values.
                    visitRommsDFS(rooms, i, j, 0, roomsBool);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void visitRommsDFS(int[][] rooms, int row, int col, int count, boolean[][] roomsBool){
        if(row < 0 || row >= rooms.length || col < 0 || col >= rooms[row].length || rooms[row][col] == -1 || rooms[row][col] == 0 && count > 0) return;

        rooms[row][col] =  count;
        roomsBool[row][col] = true;

        if(row > 0 && rooms[row-1][col] > count + 1)
          visitRommsDFS(rooms, row-1, col, count + 1, roomsBool);

        if(row + 1 < rooms.length && rooms[row+1][col] > count + 1)  
          visitRommsDFS(rooms, row+1, col, count + 1, roomsBool);

        if(col + 1 < rooms[row].length && rooms[row][col + 1] > count + 1)  
          visitRommsDFS(rooms, row, col+1, count + 1, roomsBool);

        if(col > 0 && rooms[row][col - 1] > count + 1) 
          visitRommsDFS(rooms, row, col-1, count + 1, roomsBool);

        roomsBool[row][col] = false;
    }
 }
```

In my humble opinion the morale of the story is to recurse definitely, recurse obviously, recurse forever, but recurse selectively and recurse wisely.

**Time Complexity Analysis**
Since the search space is a m X n grid, the complexity of the DFS, the second helper function is O(m X n), as we are covering all the cells of the grid and there are m X n of them. And the pruning when we are making a recursive call, ensures that no more repetitive traversal of a cell happens, while doing DFS.

Had I done it in BFS way then also the time complexity would have remained the same that is O(m X n), here the choice of BFS and DFS would not matter on the time complexity, as the grid size is fixed before hand and we are traversing each cell, only once, unless the distance value is smaller.

*If the distance value in the next call is smaller than the current value in the cell, then obviously we are traversing a cell more than 1 time.*

Whether we are going from a centre to larger and larger concentric circle, or we are going too deep in one direction, will not affect the complexity, in this case.

**Why?**

Because the number of cells in the given grid is limited, and even if DFS goes in one direction, it is forced to comeback from that direction by grid edges and walls.
And continue exploration in another direction, and eventually DFS covers all cells.
Also, with the logic to curtail unnecessary traversal we are being efficient in our traversal.
As does the BFS, style of traversal.
So time complexity of both the traversals is asymptotically the same with the above pruning of unwanted recursive calls.

Comment: The condition `roomsBool[row][col] == true` is superfluous, you may split your long if statement into multiple if's, place a debugger onto `if (roomsBool[row][col] == true)`  and find out that code never reaches that if.

Comment: Sure, let me check. But can we explain that why it is not going to reach at that statement.

Comment: the statement "we have seen this room before" is majorated by statement "if proposed distance is more than or equal to the current one, the room is either gate of wall or we have seen it before". So, if you would like to prove the correctness of algorithm, you need to prove the correctness of `rooms[row][col - 1] > count + 1` optimization, w/o that optimization the algorithm has exponential time complexity.